# SEO - URLS submitted in sitemap is excluded( 'Discovered not indexed ') in coverage report

Tags: seo

I submitted a new sitemap for the items that should be listed in google. But it is seen that out of 300 only 21 is indexed. Rest went to 'Discovered not indexed'. The urls in sitemap are not duplicate URLS. Contents in the URLs are dynamically generated. Can anyone explain why it is happening.

Comment: Dynamically generated content are low quality and Google might be not interested to index it ASAP. Here is some [helpful notes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29240/google-indexes-some-of-pages-but-most-are-ignored-from-a-website-even-though-a?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will definitely go through . But certain URLS are still indexed by Google.This is what really confusing me.